# langchain qa retrieval chain can't filter by specific docs

Tags: langchain, chromadb

trying to use RetrievalQA with Chromadb to create a Q&A bot on our company's documents. general setup as below:

import libs

```
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma # for storing and retrieving vectors
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings # for embedding text
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter # for splitting text into tokens
from langchain import OpenAI # for using the OpenAI API
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA # for question and answer retrieval
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader # for loading documents from a directory
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
import magic
import os
import nltk
```

loading docs, chunking, embedding

```
loader = DirectoryLoader('dir',glob='**/*.txt')
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2000, chunk_overlap = 100)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
persist_directory = 'db'
docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(
    texts, 
    embeddings,
    persist_directory=persist_directory
```

then start the chain and ask question

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.1, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo', cache=False,verbose=True)
chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT_1}
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(search_kwargs = {'filter': {'source':'DB_Manual.txt'}}), chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs)

query = "what's our company's dress code?"
result = qa.run(query)
result
```

with multiple doc in db, the search_kwargs doesn't seem to work consistently.

i tried to ask about dress code while filtering to a manual (which doesn't have anything to do with dress code), expecting it to give me idk as the answer, but sometimes it would still give me the correct answer about dress code.

i feel like it's because of the metadata, maybe by default chroma doesnt include 'source' as metadata and i need to load the docs in with 'source' metadata defined explicitly? if so does anyone know how to do that through langchain?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here.

I print out the number of retrieved docs and always get 0. Here is the code, which you can also try to see if anything is being retrieved:

```
# Create a retriever
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 2})
docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents(query)

print(f'Number of retrieved docs = {len(docs)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is working for me, with Lanchain version 0.0.223.

```
import os

from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain 
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('../../.env')

document_directory = '../../data'

embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings(
    openai_api_key=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    deployment=os.getenv('EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME'),
    model=os.getenv('EMBEDDING_MODEL'),
    chunk_size=1) 
    
loader = DirectoryLoader(document_directory)
documents = loader.load()

db = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embedding_function)

llm = AzureOpenAI(deployment_name=os.getenv('CHAT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME'), 
                    model_name=os.getenv('CHAT_MODEL'), 
                    temperature=0, openai_api_version='2023-05-15')

vec = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"filter": {"source":'..\\..\\data\\musk-article-1.txt'}})

qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm = llm, 
                                            retriever = vec, 
                                            return_source_documents = True)

response = qa({"question": "Who is William Rich?", "chat_history": []})

print(response['answer'])
```

I have two articles. The first article specifically mentions William Rich, and the second does not.

When I run this with:

```
vec = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"filter": {"source":'..\\..\\data\\musk-article-1.txt'}})
```

I get:

```
William Rich is an Employee
```

But when I change the source document to:

```
vec = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"filter": {"source":'..\\..\\data\\musk-article-2.txt'}})
```

I get:

```
"William Rich is not mentioned in the context"
```

Which proves that the source filtering is working, since William Rich is not mentioned in musk-article-2.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/2095) for langchain related to your problem.

Doing this directly seems to work:

```
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
                        OpenAI(temperature=0),
                        VectorStoreRetriever(vectorstore=vectorstore, search_kwargs={"filter":{"tenant":"commerce-hub"}}),
                        callback_manager=manager,
                        verbose = True,
                        return_source_documents=True)
```

Not sure if this will help you, but I ran across a similar issue using the mongodb vector store.

I was using MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch as a retriever and trying to filter as follows [per the documentation](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain.vectorstores.mongodb_atlas.MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch.html#langchain.vectorstores.mongodb_atlas.MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch.as_retriever):

```
# Use a filter to only retrieve documents from a specific paper
docsearch.as_retriever(
    search_kwargs={'filter': {'paper_title':'GPT-4 Technical Report'}}
)
```

However, when I [found this post on the mongodb help page](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/filtering-the-results-of-vector-search-with-langchain/240608/2) they showed the following (they should've used 'defaultPath' instead of 'path' in this example but the rest is correct):

```
search_kwargs={
    'k': k * 10,
    'pre_filter': {
        'text': {
            'path': 'project',
            'query': 'heroes'
        }
    },
    'post_filter_pipeline': [ { '$limit': k } ]
}
```

If you take a look at what the person helping said they mentioned that their implementation in mongodb was unique to them.

All this is to say that chroma may have modified their documentation on how to filter by metadata as it relates to Chroma and Langchain. I would take a look and see how they implement it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'll caution that this is for the *javascript/typescript* side of langchain, but maybe it'll help someone with an overall hint on what worked for me.

**NOTE**: I am also using Milvus as a vectorstore, so it is possible that each of the vectorstores might have some vectorstore-specific logic with respect to filtering.

I got very frustrated trying to figure out what the heck could possibly be listed as a filter, since I was trying to do a very simple boolean expression.

I dug into the langchain vectorstore for Milvus located in *node_modules/langchain/dist/vectorstores/milvus.cjs* and found the filter was just a string in this method: `async similaritySearchVectorWithScore(query, k, filter) {`

I ended up with this.  The first argument is the `k` and the second is the simple filter.

```
   const retriever = await vectorStore.asRetriever(10, 'is_a_client == FALSE');
```

Alternatively, I could also specify them as a config object like:

```
  const retrieverOptions = {
    k: 10,
    filter: 'is_a_client == TRUE',
  }
  const retriever = await vectorStore.asRetriever(retrieverOptions);
```

I had to play around with acceptable expressions a bit though to figure out the `== TRUE` in all caps bit.
The boolean expression rules were listed in the Milvus client documentation [here](https://milvus.io/docs/boolean.md). It did reference that the Python filtering worked in a similar way.

Anyway, I hope that it will help someone.  I find that when I hit langchain issues, I'm desperate for a clue or example and often I only have a single python or javascript stackoverflow post to guide me.